# How to get custom fields in association table Sequelize js

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

"I want to get some attributes of an include table instead of using *, my code right now is this.

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/post', function(req, res){
        model.Post.findAll(
            { attributes: ["body", "id"],
            {include: [model.User]).success(function(rows){
                    res.json(rows);
            }

        );


    });
```

This works fine , but the query gets some data  that i really don't need( password, birth, email) How can i get only , for example the username and avatar of the inlclude table User?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify what you want back via the attributes property. I'm not sure what your schema looks like, so I may need to look a little different, but here's my best guess:

```
// If password, birth, and email are nested in the body:
{ attributes: ["body.username", "body.avatar", "id"],
...
```

That should work. If not, please post your schema.

Comment: did you mean `{ attributes: ["body", ["username", "avatar"], "id"], ...`?

Comment: I'm not sure that my syntax was right, but how you have it, it will return `body`, `id`, and rename the `username` attribute to `avatar`.

Comment: The only thing I know is that the code in your answer has a syntax error at the second colon.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is still not correct. Right answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21907320/601466