# Using sequelize join table, how do I set the key of the attributes grabbed while joining?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So this is kind of in reference to this question
[How to use an include with attributes with sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883484/how-to-use-an-include-with-attributes-with-sequelize)

The question helped me to grab the attributes of the joined table, but when I grab the attributes, the keys would start with a singular version of the table grabbed.  So from the example above the resulting object returned should be something like...

```
{
    id: yada,
    name: yada,
    bar.version: yada,
    bar.changed: yada
}
```

Is there anyway to exclude the table name (bar) in front of the keys?

Comment: You can add a new alias for the table, but afaik excluding is not possible. Take a look at this [thread](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3440) for reference.